# C code works in VS, but fails when going through valgrind and refuses to compile

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I have written the following code for a school assignment (C basics)

```
#include "source.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


char *my_toupper(char *dest, const char *src)
{   
    
    char *RET = dest;
    while (*src!= '\0' ){
        if (isalpha(*src)){
            char a = *src;
            a = toupper(a);
            *dest = a; 
        }
        else if (*src =='.'){
            *dest = '!';
            dest++;
            *dest = '!';
            dest++;
            *dest = '!';
        }
        else if (*src == '?'){
            *dest = '!';
        }
        else {
            strcpy(dest,src);
        }

        src ++;
        dest++;
    }
    return RET;
}
```

The code is supposed to take a string, and then change all of the letters to uppercase, change '?' to '!' and when encountering a '.', change it to '!!!'. This is supposed to be written in dest, and the pointer is supposed to be returned pointing to its original position.
Now, the problem is, that when I run the code through a debugger in Visual Studio Code, everything works just fine (tested with multiple different strings), but when I try to return the assignment, the code refuses to work, and the system gives me 0/20 points.
I get the following messages for compiling:

```
g++ -c -isystem ../../../gcheck -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I../../../gcheck/include test_source.cpp -o test_source.o
python3 ../../../scripts/main_remover.py ../src/source.c ../src/source.c
cc -c -isystem ../../../gcheck -std=c99 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers ../src/source.c -o source.o
g++ test_source.o source.o -L../../../gcheck/lib -lgcheck   -o test
```

and running:

```
rm -f test test_source.o source.o  valgrind.log mockinput mockoutput report.json
g++ -c -isystem ../../../gcheck -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I../../../gcheck/include test_source.cpp -o test_source.o
python3 ../../../scripts/main_remover.py ../src/source.c ../src/source.c
cc -c -isystem ../../../gcheck -std=c99 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers ../src/source.c -o source.o
g++ test_source.o source.o -L../../../gcheck/lib -lgcheck   -o test
valgrind -q --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --log-file=valgrind_out.txt ./test --json
```

I have figured out that this is due to '!' being added three times when encountering '.', as when I return the following code with the '!' only being printed once, it works just fine.

```
#include "source.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


char *my_toupper(char *dest, const char *src)
{   
    
    char *RET = dest;
    while (*src!= '\0' ){
        if (isalpha(*src)){
            char a = *src;
            a = toupper(a);
            *dest = a; 
        }
        else if (*src =='.'){
            *dest = '!';
            
        }
        else if (*src == '?'){
            *dest = '!';
        }
        else {
            strcpy(dest,src);
        }

        src ++;
        dest++;
    }
    return RET;
}
```

I will also put the main-function here so you can get an idea of that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "source.h"

int main(void)
{
    char dest[200];

    /* The following helps detecting string errors, e.g. missing final nil */
    memset(dest, '#', 199);
    dest[199] = 0;
    printf("%s",
        my_toupper(dest, "a?b?1.2.c??d..\n"));

    printf("%s",
        my_toupper(dest, "Madam, where are you going? The health care center is over there.\n"));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your questions, it is unreadable

Comment: Your call to `strcpy` makes no sense. Why do you copy a string for every character?

Comment: You need to add `'\0'` to the end of `dest`. Your code _appears_ to work because none of the test cases ends in a special char (`.` or `?`), therefore, the `strcpy` is the last action in the loop and that appends the `'\0'` for you. If you try a string that does end in special char, no `'\0'` is appended and the string ends up with a bunch of `'#`' at the end.